# Ubuntu programs to run on startup

Tags: ubuntu

I have 2 programs that are end-less and I want to run both of them in the background when I start up my Ubuntu server. Right now I have in my rc.local:

```
setsid mono ../root/Check.exe

setsid sh ../root/blabla.sh
```

Both of them are endless so Check.exe never exits, therefor blabla.sh never runs. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nohup` which stops the process receiving the `NOHUP` signal and thus terminating if you log out of the shell the program was invoked with. `&` runs a process in the background.

```
nohup setsid mono ../root/Check.exe &

nohup setsid sh ../root/blabla.sh &
```